# Creating own toggle button in WP8?

Tags: c#, android, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I need to port an Android app which has a widget to WP8.

For this I need to create my own toggle button (user control). So I just created a subclass of Button called MyToggleButton and use the standard callbacks to change the image and the text of the button.

To catch the click down I use `onMouseEnter` and when the click is finished, ie the moud button goes up again I use `onMouseLeave`

Wihle this works without problems - the issue is that when clicking the `onMouseEnter`seems to be called with a little delay and this button changes the ButtonImage with a minimal delay as opposed to a normal button ( I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 with Emulator since I do not yet have a real phone for testing)

WHile I found other ways of creating user controls specifing lots in XAML, however I find the described way of just using the standard methods easier. I am just not sure, where this minimal delay comes from.

Comment: I may be a better idea to derive from `CheckBox` or `RadioButton` this way you have the built in feature of `IsChecked`(toggle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified "Toggle" button using images. based on `CheckBox`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" >
            <Setter Property="Template" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Part_Content" />
                            <Image Name="image" Source="/WpfApplication4;component/Images/avatar63.jpg" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true" >
                                <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="/WpfApplication4;component/Images/imagesCA7JZMMY.jpg"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False" >
                                <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="/WpfApplication4;component/Images/avatar63.jpg"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: thanks very much, but when I copy your code in my project (using VisualStudioExpress2012) I get an error at TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox} - Type is not supported in a Silverlight project. SO I replace it with: TargetType="CheckBox". But also ControlTemplate.Triggers is not recognized - I am just starting with WP8 and downloaded the normal SDK8 from the homepage. Do I probably have a wrong setup?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not make a custom toggle in the first case. Porting an application from Android doesn't mean you also have to port its graphics. They simply don't share the same design language. You should probably stick to the native WP8 toggle.

However, if you really want to create a custom checkbox/toggle, you should check [this](http://dotnetventures.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/custom-checkbox-template-for-windows-phone-7-image-checkbox/). This was made for WP7, but it also applies to WP8.