# Change button background image when click in Windows Phone using XAML only?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

So basically I want to have a button with a certain background image.

For example, when the app is loaded you would see a button with it's background image as image1.png and then when it is clicked you see image2.png as the background image.  Then when you click again, the background image is switched back to image1.png.

Even though I have done this in C#, I want to do it in XAML because every time you click a button it automatically lights up according to the theme color, and the only way to get rid of that is via XAML.

Here is my code so fa:

```
<Button x:Name="Buttons" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,0,0,69" BorderBrush="Transparent" Width="140"  Click="Button_Click" Height="141" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Assets/image1.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes you could change the background through `XAML`, but if you want to change it through an `OnClick` or `Tap` event, you have to use c# (EventHandler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/02/15/customize-windows-phone-togglebutton.aspx

Here, the ToggleButton that ships with the SDK has been templated to add a clicked and unclicked image.

Alternate Solution with a checkbox:

[Creating own toggle button in WP8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850517/creating-own-toggle-button-in-wp8)

Answer (score 0):

VisualStudio 2017 "Blank App"

XAML

```
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.258,-5" Click="Button_Click" Height="80" Width="80"/>
```

C# (Set the original image in the properties of the button: right-click -> Brush -> image)

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/timerg.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) };

    }
```

or C#

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            Uri u = new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/timer.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            bmp.UriSource = u;
            // NOTE: change starts here
            Image i = new Image();
            i.Source = bmp;
            button1.Content = i;
    }
```